# how to avoid an application hanging while calculating two functions together?

Tags: android, distance, tcpclient, freeze

```
   float totalKm =  Contsants.jobEndKm-Contsants.jobStartKm ;
    jcTotalKms.setText(String.format("%.2f",totalKm));
    //jcTotalKms.setText(Float.toString((float) (totalKm/16.0)));
    //finding total fare here
    //int value=100;
    if (totalKm<Contsants.minDist)
    {
        jcWaitingFare.setText("0");
        float totalfare=Contsants.minFare;
        jcTotalFare.setText(String.format("%.2f",(totalfare)));
        Contsants.jobTotalKm= totalKm;
        Contsants.jobTotalFare=totalfare;
    }
    else
    {
        jcWaitingFare.setText(Integer.toString((Contsants.cont_WaitingTimeInSec/60)*1));
        float totalfare= Contsants.minFare+ ((totalKm-Contsants.minDist) *Contsants.rupeeKm)  +(Contsants.cont_WaitingTimeInSec/60)*1;
        jcTotalFare.setText(String.format("%.2f",(totalfare)));
        Contsants.jobTotalKm= totalKm;
        Contsants.jobTotalFare=totalfare;
    }
```

tcpsocket class

```
   public class tcpSocket extends Thread{
static boolean startSocket=false;
public static final String SERVERIP = "ip address here"; //your computer IP address
public static final int SERVERPORT = 8900;

private static  boolean mRun = false;
public static   Socket socket;
public static OnMessageReceived mMessageListener;

public static OnMessageReceived getmMessageListener() {
    return mMessageListener;
}
public static void setmMessageListener(OnMessageReceived mMessageListener) {
    tcpSocket.mMessageListener = mMessageListener;

}
public tcpSocket()
{

}
@Override
public void run(){
    //some long operation
    startSocket=true;
    while(startSocket)
    {
        try {
            //here you must put your computer's IP address.
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
            Log.d("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");
            //create a socket to make the connection with the server
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            try {
                //send the message to the server
                Log.d("TCP Client", "C: Sent.");
                Log.d("TCP Client", "C: Done.");
                final OutputStream out =socket.getOutputStream();
                writeResponse(out, "$0001~01~"+Contsants.Cont_IMEINo+"~Version#");
                //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
                final InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
                while(!mRun)
                {
                    if (!(in.available() > 0)) {
                        goSleep(2000);
                        continue;
                    }
                    processClient(in);
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }finally{
                socket.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("tcp error",e.toString());
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
}
private   void goSleep(final long milliSec) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(milliSec);
    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e("server conn Thread ","Sleeping client interrupted" + e);
    }
}
private void processClient(final InputStream in) throws IOException {
    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    final char[] cbuf = new char[1024];
    final int length = reader.read(cbuf);
    if (length <= 0) {
        Log.d("d","No data read from client.");
        return;
    }
    cbuf[length] = '@';
    String packet   = new String(cbuf, 0, length + 1);
    if (!packet.startsWith("$") && !packet.contains("#")) {
        Log.d("d","Invalid packet recieved: " + packet);
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        if(!packet.contains("$0002") && !packet.contains("$0423"))
        {
            final String [] packetDo=packet.split("\\~");
            writeResponse(socket.getOutputStream(), "$102~"+packetDo[1]+"~"+Contsants.Cont_IMEINo+"#");
        }
        Log.d("d","Recived packet is :"+packet);

        Message msg = new Message();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("ServerMsg", packet);
        msg.setData(b);
        // send message to the handler with the current message handler
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("TCP", "p: Error", e);
    }
}

 Handler mHandler =new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message){
        //update UI
        Bundle b = message.getData();
        final String data =b.getString("ServerMsg");
        mMessageListener.messageReceived(data);
    }
};
/*public class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String response = null;
        return SendMessage(response);
    }

}

public static boolean SendMessage(final String response) {

    OutputStream out;
    try {
        out = socket.getOutputStream();
        writeResponse(out, response);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        mRun = true;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
*/
public static boolean SendMessage(final String response) 
{
    OutputStream out;
    try {
        out = socket.getOutputStream();
        writeResponse(out,response);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        mRun=true;
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
private static  void writeResponse(final OutputStream out, final String response) throws IOException {
    // logger.info("Sending response to client: " + response);
    out.write(response.getBytes());
    out.flush();
}
 }
```

here is my code for calculating distance and fare together when the condition exceeds minimum(minDist) kilometer. But while checking this application in real device it hangs up after two kilometer. Because after two kilometer it goes to else condition part. i don't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: You need to be a lot clearer.  What *exactly* does "hanging" mean?  Do you get an application not responding message?  If so, the code you have shown cannot cause that.

Comment: ya. you are correct. the tcp socket class will be cause the hanging problem while sending message to sever. i dont know how to solve that issue.

Comment: @Simon i edited my code and updated the tcpsocket class.